# JpaInspector cannot override inspectProperty()

Tags: java, jpa

I want to use `JpaInspector` class that is written for Metawidget. However when I insert this class into my Java project in Netbeans 6.8, It gives an error for `inspectProperty()` method of `JpaInspector` class, "method does not override or implement a method from supertype". Does it mean that parent class of `JpaInspector`, that is `BaseObjectInspector`, does not have such a method? Or what should I do to use `JpaInspector` in my project?

**Update**

Ok, I import the package "org.metawidget.inspector.jpa.JpaInspector"; however, although some fields of my entity class are set as nullable = false, the stars are not seen. Why is it?

Answer (score 0):

Gulcan,

I'm confused: are you inserting the source code for JpaInspector into your project? I'm unclear why you would want to do that. You can add JpaInspector to Metawidget by using metawidget.xml and CompositeInspector. For example:

```
    <inspector>
        <compositeInspector>
            <inspectors>
                <array>
                    <metawidgetAnnotationInspector />
                    <jpaInspector />            
                </array>
            </inspectors>
```

Or you can add it programmatically. In neither case do you need the JpaInspector source code.

Regards,

Richard.

Comment: As per Jonathan's request, please take this discussion out of Stack Overflow and post it on the Metawidget forums (https://sourceforge.net/projects/metawidget/forums/forum/747623)

Comment: Specific programming *questions* are always welcome here. But we do try to keep *discussions* limited to comments if they're absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Jonathan: yes, I completely agree and respect that. Thanks for all your work looking after this board.